# Checking SMS for Multiple Keywords in Android

Tags: java, android, sms, smsmanager

Just wondering if I could get some advice about how next to handle my App, currently I have class called: **MySMSReceiver.java**, it can check if an incoming SMS has a particular keyword that had been placed in the incoming SMS. It works fine with just checking the one word "Locate" on it's own but, I can seem to figure out how to check say 3 different Keywords on an incoming message.

Below is the code that I'm currently using for the **MySMReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.myautosms;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private String[] keyword = {"Locate", "Lock", "Unlock"};

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
        SmsMessage shortMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[0]);
        if(shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, keyword.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, keyword.to, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be welcomed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you require either of the 3 keywords.

Just check all 3 keywords :

```
if(shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword[0]) ||
   shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword[1]) ||
   shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword[2]))
```

Or if each keyword has different behavior :

```
if(shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword[0])) {

} else if (shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword[1])) {

} else if (shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().equals(keyword[2])) {

} else {

}
```

In addition, consider using case insensitive keywords, i.e. use `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: wouldn't you want to use `contains` here instead of equals? it would never pass that if statement using equals unless the message was the keyword

Comment: @tyczj That entirely depends on the requirements of the OP. Should "Locked" behave the same as "Lock" or "Don't Lock"?

Answer (score 0):

You may check multiple words in your sms content as below:

```
String body = shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody().toLowerCase();

boolean isAvailable = false;
for(String word : keyword)
    if(body.contains(word.toLowerCase()))
        isAvailable = true;

//do whatever with 'isAvailable'
```